# Splitting comma separated string of likes into smaller parts

Tags: php, facebook, string, loops

What is the best way to split a comma separated list of 50++ numbers (FB page IDs) into smaller chunks and deal with them *n* at a time?  The list will look like:

```
$likeslist="266037406871517,81337462601,34782298000891,56859608486,8797601255,48126111909968,8807449704,3634204295,6840064056,16627954050,7581229254,282681243370,356780606553962,207549746039055,13708123117519,204852972922619,407056596017784,584207664985882,11141618921610,66707529019,271953746236343,9576298621,40575497158,29252725868524,210237443769975,469586875072133,32693104762450,262744428996,506144412803606,52385706779438";
```

Because the total number in $likeslist will vary (could be hundreds), is it faster to get the total number we are working with using explode or substr_count? (**question 1**)

```
$likesarray = explode(",", $likeslist);
$result = count($likeslist);
```

OR

```
$listtotal = substr_count($likeslist, ",") +1;
```

Then, how can I divide $likeslist into smaller groups (of say, 5) and loop through each ID within in each group? (**question 2**)

Comment: You can explode it into a list, like you did, and use a `for` loop to append every 5 IDs, and add to an array. Why would you want to divide it into smaller groups anyway? Just loop through the whole list...

Comment: I have a list of likes and want to query the Facebook graph API to find out what category each like is in (eg. TV shows, music etc) by passing multiple IDs to the API at once (5 at a time)

Comment: You can split an array into chunks using `array_chunk` but what would be the point if you are going to loop through all id's in all groups any way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go ahead and make a big array.  It has to be pretty darn big to exhaust all your memory (and you can change your memory limits in the configuration).

To process sections of the list, just use a loop and the `array_slice()` function:

```
$likeslist = explode(',', $likeslist);    
$listLen = count($likeslist);
$chunkSize = 5;

for($offset=0; $offset<$listLen; $offset+=$chunkSize) {
    $subList = array_slice($likeslist, $offset, $chunkSize);
    // do whatever to your sublist 
    print_r($subList);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use multi-dimensional arrays.

```
$likes = explode(",", $likesList);
$l5 = array(); // multi-dimensional array containing arrays of only 5 likes
$i = 0; // counter for how many items we have per sub-array
$c = 0; // counter for what index of $l5 we are on
foreach($likes as $l) {
    if ( $i >= 5 ) {
        $c++; // increment array index
        $i = 0; // reset counter for the next 5 entries
    }
    $l5[$c][] = $l;
    $i++;
}
```